# Stop Visual Studio text editor from auto moving comment lines

Tags: c#, visual-studio, formatting, text-editor

Is there a way (or tool) to stop Visual Studio text editor (2015 or 2017) from auto moving the comment lines when pressing Ctrl+K,D or relevant key stroke (Ctrl+E,D - format entire document) ?

I would like my comments to stay at the position placed, regardless of the code position above or below.
For example, when writing a comment line starting say at col 80 as

code line
|--------    white space -------------------| //... comment ..
code line

so that **it doesn't interfere with the code below or above**, when pressing Ctrl+K,D the comment is shifted left to align with the surrounding code.

On the other hand, when a comment is placed following a code line, as below

|----code line ------|-- white space --| //.... 1st comment line ....
|-------white space ---------------------| //.... 2nd comment line....

an eventual 2nd comment line remains aligned with the above one, which indicates that the editor  can adjust the position of comment lines based on certain criteria

**Edit:** I should clarify that I would like to preserve the rest of the functionality of Ctrl+K,D

Comment: This question is off topic, there is nothing to do with programming.

Comment: You should ask this on Super User.

Comment: Well, questions about how to use programming tools are allowed. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288832/which-questions-about-programming-tools-are-allowed

Comment: Related topic: [Disable auto-indent of comments with Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43899505/disable-auto-indent-of-comments-with-visual-studio-2015)